# TinyMCE custom toolbar menuItem click triggers click events of all parent items

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I'm adding a custom toolbar button to my tinyMCE like this

```
tinyMCE.init({
mode: "specific_textareas", 
editor_selector: "mceEditor",
width: 600,
toolbar_items_size: "small",
plugins: ["advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor","searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen","insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste "],
toolbar: "undo redo | styleselect | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image | stats ",
setup: function (editor) {
editor.addButton('stats',{
    text: 'Stats',
    type: 'menubutton',
    icon: false,
    menu: [
    {
    text: 'item1',
    selectable: 'false',
    classes: 'noselect',
    onclick: function () { editor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, '{rootValue}');},
    menu: [
    {
    text: 'item1.1',
    selectable: 'false',
    classes: 'noselect',
    onclick: function () { editor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, '{midValue}');},
    menu: [
    {
    text: 'item1.1.1',
    selectable: 'false',
    classes: 'noselect',
    onclick: function () { editor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, '{leafValue}');},
    },
    ]
    },
    ]
    },
    ]
    });}});
```

So my button is a menu which has submenus, and those submenus can have submenus and so on, so I have multiple nested submenus and each of them have an onclick function that inserts some text into the editor. The problem I'm running into is that when I click the innermost button for example it triggers all the onclick events on the tree path from the root. So If I click on the button that should insert {leafValue}, it inserts this

```
{leafValue}{midValue}{rootValue}
```

Obviously I would like to insert only leafValue here. Is this a known tinyMCE issue ?Anyone know how can I fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use `preventDefault()`?

```
onclick:function (evt) { 
    editor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, '{leafValue}');
    evt.preventDefault();
}
```

MDN: http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/#event-preventDefault

Comment: Tried this, but it didn't work (still inserting all the unwanted text). Probably because the onclick function is handled by tinyMCE internally.

Comment: Nevermind, I forgot to add the source object as a function parameter. It works now ! Thanks!